# mac os x Qgis 2.18 python console

Tags: qgis-processing, mac

I have made some python script to run under Processing toolbox.
A lot of these scripts use Gdal library and runs smoothly under windows and Linux.
But in mac os x 10.12.6 using qgis 2.18 the Gdal library is not exposed to the python console. I mean if i try

```
from os import system
```

`system('ls')`

I got 0, which means that it is ok
But if I type

`system('gdal_translate')`

I got 32512 which means command not found.
Of course if I run python from a terminal it is ok.

Comment: What version of QGIS did you install ? (Kyng Chaos, Homebrew, ...)

Comment: Can you reproduce this using a code snippet?

Comment: The QGIS version that I installed is Kyng Chaos.